# Python Game of Nim Binary Tree

Tags: python, function, binary-tree, minimax

I have been trying to work on this for a while-I am trying to use a Binary tree for this implementation, with recursion.

For this assignment, I am trying to get a list of all possibilities for Game of Nim: So far I have the split function (Thanks to Eric Duminal):

```
def split(n):
  return [[i, n - i] for i in range(1, (n + 1) // 2)]
```

which returns a list of lists, example: n=6 would return [[1,5],[2,4]], which is what I want. (No duplicates, and non-zeros)
Now, I need to basically use that split function for anything that is 3 or greater (since 2 and 1 are the "base" cases").

For example: I would need to generate something like this, within a binary tree-type node:

for n=6

```
\-[6] Max
  + [1, 5]
  |  + [1,1,4]
  |   \-[1, 1, 1, 3] Min
  |     \-[1, 1, 1, 1, 2] Max
  |   \-[1, 2, 3] Max
  |     \-[1, 1, 2, 2] Min
  \-[2, 4] Min
     \-[1, 2, 3] Max
        \-[1, 1, 2, 2] Min
```

So within [1,5] and [2,4], I would need to generate all the possibilities and make them within the same list. 
-How would I use recursion for this type of problem? Each split cannot contain duplicates, non-empty sets.
Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is the basic partitions problem. You could define a function have two parameter n and m which n is just your number and m is using parts up to. So partition(n,m) will equal to the number of ways to partition n-m using integers up to m and the number of ways to partition n using integers up to m-1. And you could still use your function split to get your result.